# How do I make an application think it is running from desktop server (e.g gdm3)?

Tags: command-line, xorg, gdm, opengl

I have an application binary that works fine if I run it from a terminal in an windows environment (say gdm).

If I run it from raw console (Ctrl+Alt+F3), it emits errors.

But I do need to run this from console.

Is there any way I can run it from console, but make it 'think' it is running from a terminal in a windows environment?

What I tried -

- I already tried "export DISPLAY=:0", which didn't do the trick.
- I suspect it depends on a graphics library, may be opengl for some computations, which is not properly initialized if I run from console.

Answer (score 2):

Your question, "How can I run a Graphical User Interface (GUI) program in a non-GUI environment?" can't be done. The program depends on the GUI to open windows, etc.

If you had said which program, maybe someone could suggest a Command Line Interface (CLI) equivalent.

If there is another X windows display available (and where you want the program's output to be displayed) on `localhost`, or even on your LAN, read `man xhost`.